# Level normalization of microphone input

Tags: javascript, microphone, audiocontext

I have a problem using JavaScript Web Audio API since actualization Firefox to version 31. The source of my script is unchanged.

What it does? I use microphone input (generated waveforms ported through 3.5mm jack into PC), --> gain --> visualization using ScriptProcessor node. And - everything worked fine but now it seems to me, that the input levels are being somehow normalized before sent to the GainNode. The result is that the waveform visualization is totally unusable. Example below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzEOR.png

I cannot find any way to switch this feature off. The only thing that works is to downgrade FF to version 30. I've searched in release notes of FF 31, though, I haven't found anything which would explain this behavior...

Is there any way to solve that? Why is this happening?
Thank you.